# Is saying 100 berachot daily biblical or rabbinic

Tags: halacha, blessing, derabanan, orach-chaim, deorayta

In halacha, Jews should recite 100 berachot a day. My question is, is this requirement a biblical law or a rabbinic decree?

Comment: It's disputed: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Making_One_Hundred_Brachot_Daily#cite_note-4